# Add right arrow in visual studio code

Tags: laravel

In [this nice tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch/episodes/9) at 00:47, the guy adds a right arrow. Ho do I do this? I tried to do it by ALT+26, does not work. He simply inserts it somehow.

Comment: php have defined code for symbols, you can find the code for the arrows https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_arrows.asp

Comment: @Prospero That's [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), a character encoding. Not exclusive to PHP

Comment: @shaedrich you're right...it's HTML unicode UTF-8 stuff

Comment: @Prospero: No, the arrow is not visible in the web page, it is just used in the code. He adds it in his code editor.

Comment: @Simon2019, could you give me the link of the video, of the correct episode and time to look what was the author solution?

Comment: @Prospero: Thanks, I corrected the link.

Comment: dude, are you talking about this right arrow direction??? " -> " in the route definition? It's just joining - (dash) and > (greater-than sign)

Answer (score 2):

```json
{
  "editor.fontLigatures": true,
  "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code, 'Courier New', monospace",
  "editor.fontSize": 14
}
```

My config for User Settings and font "Fira Code".

[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ez4v1.png)